How to Convert RegisterDecorator from Simple Injector to .NET Core's IServiceCollection?
I'm trying to migrate some code from Simple Injector's RegisterDecorator pattern which is in .Net Framework to .NET Core's IServiceCollection. In Simple Injector, my code looks like this:
container.Register<IContentGetHandler, AssembleContent>(Lifetime.Singleton);
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IContentGetHandler), typeof(RemoveUnsupportedFields), Lifetime.Singleton);
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IContentGetHandler), typeof(LoadContentBaseFields), Lifetime.Transient);
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IContentGetHandler), typeof(AddFieldsWithoutValues), Lifetime.Transient);
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IContentGetHandler), typeof(SetCalcFieldErrors), Lifetime.Transient);
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IContentGetHandler), typeof(HandleAssembleException), Lifetime.Transient);

I attempted to convert this to an IServiceCollection with the following method:
public void RegisterDecorator(Type serviceType, Type decoratorType, Lifetime lifeTime)
{
    var serviceDescriptor = _services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == serviceType);
    if (serviceDescriptor == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Service of type {serviceType.Name} not registered.");
    }

    if (serviceDescriptor.ImplementationType == null)
    {
        _services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);
    }

    _services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(serviceType, decoratorType, MapLifetime(lifeTime)));
}

I am able to see the instances are getting created in the service collection, but when I do the serviceLocator.getRequiredService<IContentGetHandler>(); it throws the exception as circular dependency issue.
I'm encountering issues with this approach and I'm not sure why it's not working as expected. Specifically:

How do I properly register decorators in .NET Core’s DI system?
Is there a better way to handle removing and re-adding services when using decorators with IServiceCollection?
What’s the best way to ensure the correct order of execution for these decorators in .NET Core?

Any help or insights would be highly appreciated!

There's no built-in functionality for this. .NET Core's DI is just a DI service. What Simple Injector decorators do goes beyond DI into aspect oriented programming. Check Andrew Lock's article that shows how to implement this either manually or using a specialized library, Scrutor. The manual way, using a factory method, is a lot simpler than this code and in the end, doesn't take more lines to express than Simple Injector

On top of that, the types in this question look more like steps in a pipeline than actual decorators. ASP.NET Core's middleware uses a pipeline of filters to implement similar functionality. Instead of decorating HttpRequest with AuthenticatedHttpRequest, the Authentication middleware is added in the request processing pipeline

Another option is to integrate SimpleInjector with .NET DI with builder.Services.AddSimpleInjector and use SimpleInjector as the DI of the entire application

@PanagiotisKanavos Thank you very much for your response. I will try the last option which u have mentioned.

@PanagiotisKanavos I am using Host application not the Web Application. Will it be same or is there any different way to implement it ?

Yes. Both create the same hosting infrastructure but WebApplication adds middleware and settings used in web apps. The DI, Logging, Configuration middleware is the same
